# Local Variable in Sql Select Query

Tags: sql

I have a following table with the data

```
--------------------
Name    |   Status
--------|-----------     
AAA     |    Active
BBB     |    Active
CCC     |    Active
```

I am trying to get the select query work by using local variable but the query is not working and I am not getting any result.

```
declare
   @v1 nvarchar(100)=null,
   @v2 nvarchar(100)=null

set @v1='AAA'
set @v2 =' and Name=' + '''' + @v1 + ''''

SELECT * 
FROM Employe  
WHERE status = 'Active'  + @v2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you will be creating the Where clause dynamically from the variable the Query needs to be prepared as a string and then executed by using `exec` command.

That is because you will need to prepare a dynamic SQL Query

```
declare
@v1 nvarchar(100)=null,   
@v2 nvarchar(100)=null,
@SQL nvarchar(4000) = null 

set @v1='AAA'
set @v2 =' and Name=' + '''' + @v1 + ''''

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM  Employe  WHERE  status = ''Active'''  + @v2

EXEC @SQL
```

Comment: Getting the error = Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT * FROM  Employe  WHERE  status = 'Active' and Name='AAA''.

Comment: Add a single quote before AAA, just format it correct that the complete line is in red, except `+ @v2`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `@v2`

```
declare
@v1 nvarchar(100)=null

set @v1='AAA'

SELECT * FROM  Employe  WHERE  status = 'Active' and Name = @v1
```

Comment: The real situation is worst than this simple coding. I have a more than 50 lines stored procedure and I have simple it down for the understanding.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the dynamic SQL query is  conditional usage of the variable in the where clause, like below

```
declare @v1 nvarchar(100)=null,    
set @v1='AAA'
SELECT * FROM  Employe  WHERE  status = 'Active'  AND (@v1 IS NULL OR Name = @v1)
```

The code above will return all records regardless of the name if the variable is NULL. When the variable is not NULL it will filter the query for the variable value.

Comment: You should remove the `,`